# Finding SQL Server Instance & service pack build with PowerShell

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, wmi

I am trying to create a script to look at a list of servers from a .txt doc and find the SQL instances that are on that server as well as the sql service pack version build for each instance. The script runs but returns no info. I think I am having trouble with the $svcPack variable and the corresponding variables that find the data needed. Any help would be greatly appriciated. Thanks.

```
    # Continue even if there are errors
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue";

# load the SQL SMO assembly
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo") | Out-Null
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum") | Out-Null
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo") | Out-Null

# Sets the server versions
$vs2005sp4 = "9.00.5000";
$vs2008sp3 = "10.00.5500.0";
$vs2008r2sp2 = "10.50.4000.0";

# EMAIL PROPERTIES
    # Set the recipients of the report.
        $users = "test@test.com"
        #$users = "You@company.com" # I use this for testing by uing my email address.
        #$users = "you@company.com", "manager@company.com", "etc@company.com";  # can be sent to individuals.


# REPORT PROPERTIES
    # Path to the report
        $reportPath = "c:\Scripts\Reports\";

    # Report name
        $reportName = "ServicePackRpt_$(get-date -format ddMMyyyy).html";

# Path and Report name together
$servicePackReport = $reportPath + $reportName

#Set colors for table cell backgrounds
$redColor = "#FF0000"
$greenColor = "#34F01F"
$yellowColor = "#F0EC22"
$orangeColor = "#F2991D"
$whiteColor = "#FFFFFF"

# Count if any computers have low disk space.  Do not send report if less than 1.
$i = 0;

# Get computer list to check disk space
$servers = Get-Content "c:\Scripts\InPutFiles\servers.txt";
$datetime = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy_HHmmss";

# Remove the report if it has already been run today so it does not append to the existing report
If (Test-Path $servicePackReport)
    {
        Remove-Item $servicePackReport
    }

# Cleanup old files..
$Daysback = "-7"
$CurrentDate = Get-Date;
$DateToDelete = $CurrentDate.AddDays($Daysback);
Get-ChildItem $reportPath | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDelete } | Remove-Item;

# Create and write HTML Header of report
$titleDate = get-date -uformat "%m-%d-%Y - %A"
$header = "
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'>
        <title>Service Pack Report</title>
        <STYLE TYPE='text/css'>
        <!--
        td {
            font-family: Tahoma;
            font-size: 11px;
            border-top: 1px solid #999999;
            border-right: 1px solid #999999;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
            border-left: 1px solid #999999;
            padding-top: 0px;
            padding-right: 0px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            padding-left: 0px;
        }
        body {
            margin-left: 5px;
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-right: 0px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            table {
            border: thin solid #000000;
        }
        -->
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <table width='100%'>
        <tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
        <td colspan='7' height='25' align='center'>
        <font face='tahoma' color='#003399' size='4'><strong>DTG Environment Service Pack Report for $titledate</strong></font>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
"
 Add-Content $servicePackReport $header

# Create and write Table header for report
 $tableHeader = "
 <table width='100%'><tbody>
    <tr bgcolor=#CCCCCC>
        <td width='10%' align='center'>Server</td>
        <td width='15%' align='center'>Instance</td>
        <td width='5%' align='center'>Version Build</td>
        <td width='10%' align='center'>Version Name</td>
    </tr>
"
Add-Content $servicePackReport $tableHeader

# Start processing disk space reports against a list of servers
foreach($computer in $servers)
{   

    #$svcPacks = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Class win32_volume | Where-object {$_.label -ne $null} | Sort-Object -property "name"
    #$svcPacks = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Class "__NAMESPACE" -namespace "root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer"

    $svcPacks = New-Object -typeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($computer)

    $computer = $computer.toupper()

    foreach($packs in $svcPacks)
    {        
        #$instanceID = $packs.Instance;
        $versionBuild = $packs.VersionString;
        $versionName = $packs.ProductLevel;
        $color = $redColor;

        # Set background color to green if service pack is 2008r2 SP2
        if($versionBuild -eq $vs2008r2sp2)
        {
            $color = $greenColor           

            # Set background color to yellow if service pack is 2008 SP3
            if($versionBuild -eq $vs2008sp3)
            {
                $color = $yellowColor

                # Set background color to orange if service pack is 2005 SP4
                if($versionBuild -eq $vs2005sp4)
                {
                    $color = $orangeColor   

                    # Create table data rows 
                    #<td width='15%' align='center'>$instanceID</td>
                    $dataRow = "
                        <tr>
                            <td width='10%'>$computer</td>                        
                            <td width='5%' align='center'>$versionBuild</td>
                            <td width='10%' align='center'>$versionName</td>
                        </tr>
                    "

                    # If statement needed to remove label that were null
                    If ($versionID -ne 'null') 
                    {
                        Add-Content $servicePackReport $dataRow;
                        Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow "$computer $deviceID service pack build = $versionBuild";
                        $i++        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

# Create table at end of report showing legend of colors for the critical and warning
$tableDescription = "
    </table><br><table width='20%'>
        <tr bgcolor='White'>
        <td width='10%' align='center' bgcolor='#34F01F'>SQL Server 2008 R2 with SP2 - " + $vs2008r2sp2 +"</td>
        <td width='10%' align='center' bgcolor='#F0EC22'>SQL Server 2008 with SP3 - " + $vs2008sp3 +"</td>
        <td width='10%' align='center' bgcolor='#F2991D'>SQL Server 2005 with SP4 - " + $vs2005sp4 +"</td>
    </tr>
"
    Add-Content $servicePackReport $tableDescription
    Add-Content $servicePackReport "</body></html>"


# Send Notification if alert $i is greater then 0
if ($i -gt 0)
{
    foreach ($user in $users)
{
        Write-Host "Sending Email notification to $user"

        $smtpServer = "test.com"
        $smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
        $msg = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage
        $msg.To.Add($user)
        $msg.From = "NoReply@test.com"
        $msg.Subject = "Environment Service Pack Report for $titledate"
        $msg.IsBodyHTML = $true
        $msg.Body = get-content $servicePackReport
        $smtp.Send($msg)
        $body = ""
    }
  }
```

Comment: Wow… the whole script. You're more likely to get an answer if you can distill the problem down to its simplest form. That is, you're having a problem figuring out the service pack. Show us code that attempts to do just that.

Comment: the for each loops are where i am having the trouble, specifically the $svcPacks object, $versionBuild, and $versionName. they arent pulling that information from the servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, from the looks of it, it's a small mistake. When evaluating your $VersionBuild, you don't have any *else* statements. So if it fails the first evaluation:

```
if($versionBuild -eq $vs2008r2sp2)
```

Then it won't continue, and evaluate if it could be the other versions.

The other thing I would do is instead of using `-eq` in your if statements, use `-match` and shorten your version string. That way if your version string has a better chance of matching if the version string doesn't match exactly. e.g. You were trying to check the version `$vs2005sp4 = "9.00.5000";` but the VersionString property is going to return `"9.00.5000.00"` which if you use `-eq` doesn't work, but if you use `-match` it will work.

So, adding in the else statements, shortening the version strings, and using `-match` your code block will look something like this:

```
# Sets the server versions
$vs2005sp4 = "9.00.5000";
$vs2008sp3 = "10.00.5500";
$vs2008r2sp2 = "10.50.4000";

#...

    # Set background color to green if service pack is 2008r2 SP2
    if($versionBuild -match $vs2008r2sp2)
    {
        $color = $greenColor           
}
else
{
        # Set background color to yellow if service pack is 2008 SP3
        if($versionBuild -match $vs2008sp3)
        {
            $color = $yellowColor
    }
    else
    {
            # Set background color to orange if service pack is 2005 SP4
            if($versionBuild -match $vs2005sp4)
            {
                $color = $orangeColor   

                # Create table data rows 
                #<td width='15%' align='center'>$instanceID</td>
                $dataRow = "
                    <tr>
                        <td width='10%'>$computer</td>                        
                        <td width='5%' align='center'>$versionBuild</td>
                        <td width='10%' align='center'>$versionName</td>
                    </tr>
                "
    }
    else
    {
                # If statement needed to remove label that were null
                If ($versionID -ne 'null') 
                {
                    Add-Content $servicePackReport $dataRow;
                    Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow "$computer $deviceID service pack build = $versionBuild";
                    $i++        
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

-- Edit

To answer @user1700796's question, I think that the real issue that @user1700796's encountering is that this script will not work against SQL servers that have multiple instances. i.e. when you get the Smo.Server object:

```
$svcPacks = New-Object -typeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($computer)
```

Where `$computer` is a **server name**, and on that server there is multiple instances; a **single** Smo.Server object is returned, which is essentially empty. i.e. pulling the VersionString returns an empty string.

If instead, you run the same command, except you put in the full SQL server name + the instance name, for each instance, then the Smo.Server object returns the correct information.

This is because the Smo.Server object uses a SQL connection string to connect to the SQL server (see the `ConnectionContext` property), and it can only connect to a single instance at a time, and does not enumerate through your instances as you might have been expecting.

So, instead of using the foreach loop on the Smo.Server object, you need to:

- First use a couple of commands to take the computer name and enumerate the names of the SQL server instances on that box

  - For ex. See: [PowerShell list all SQL instances on my system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516337/powershell-list-all-sql-instances-on-my-system.)
- Take those SQL server instances, and *then* do a foreach loop on those names
- You use those SQL Server instance names to get your Smo.Server object
- Then you can then pull the version string from the Smo.Server object.

Comment: Thanks I went ahead and fixed those issues. I am still having trouble getting it to return the info about each server. Would you happen to know if my $svcPack object is set up correctly as well as my $versionBuild and $versionName variables? It isnt pulling any info from the servers.

Comment: You're Awesome, that worked perfectly, instead of having the code get the list of instances, I just exported a list into a txt file and im running the code on that list of isntances, sped up the run time alot. Thanks!

Comment: Great to hear! that's exactly what I would have done. I'm happy that it's working for you now!